# How can I stop the other note not just only latest note I play?

Tags: audiokit

I am trying to use AKOscillatorBank to make a piano. It works when I play individual notes, but when I play multiple notes,I can only stop the latest note when I play. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

private func setupAudio() {
       AudioKit.output = bank
       try! AudioKit.start()
       bank.play(noteNumber: UInt8(octave), velocity: 60)

  }
   private func audiostop(){
      bank.stop(noteNumber: UInt8(62))
  }
  private func audiodstop(){
    bank.stop(noteNumber: UInt8(64))
  ｝
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

@IBAction func c(_ sender: Any) {
     octave = 62
    setupAudio()
}
@IBAction func d(_ sender: Any) {
    octave = 64
   setupAudio()
}
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
    audiostop()
}
@IBAction func dstop(_ sender: Any) {
    audiodstop()
}
}
```

Any advice or pointers will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: your code works as I would expect it to: `audiostop` stops note 62, started by `c()` and `audiodstop` stops note 64, started by `d()`.  This is true even if both notes are playing - hitting both stop buttons, stops both notes. What is the problem?

Comment: By the way, you should separate the code for setting up the audio (assigning the output, and starting AudioKit) - this is called only once at the start - from the code for playing the notes,  which you can call each time you want to start playing a note.

Comment: I try again, and I found my problem is I put AKOscillatorBank setup function in func setupAudio(). Thanks for your help.